# Since regression analysis is inferential, can it be used on census data?

Tags: regression, census

I read all the comments about using inferential statistics in census studies. From generalizing point of view, it is acceptable for me to not use inferential statistics in census studies. However, I was wondering in census studies how we can assess influencing factors on our dependent variable. Considering that regression and correlation analysis are inferential techniques, how can the researcher analyze the linear relationship between two variables or relationship between several independent or predictor variables and a dependent or criterion variable?